# How to create Dataframe from Fixed_width_column (dictionary) - Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

> fixed_width_column = {
> "id": (1, 3),
> "name": (4, 3),
> "age": (7, 2),
> "salary": (9, 4)
> }

File ->
123asd122000
234dfg221000
322sfg213400
124gse235900


How to convert the file with above structure to dataframe from inferring the schema from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest, would be to use `substring` like this

```
>>> df = sc.parallelize([('123asd122000',),('234dfg221000',)]).toDF(['fullstr'])
>>> df.show()
+------------+
|     fullstr|
+------------+
|123asd122000|
|234dfg221000|
+------------+

>>> df.withColumn('id',substring('fullstr',1,3)).withColumn('name',substring('fullstr',4,3)).show()
+------------+---+----+
|     fullstr| id|name|
+------------+---+----+
|123asd122000|123| asd|
|234dfg221000|234| dfg|
+------------+---+----+

>>> df.withColumn('id',substring('fullstr',1,3)) \
... .withColumn('name',substring('fullstr',4,3)) \
... .withColumn('age',substring('fullstr',7,2)) \
... .withColumn('salary',substring('fullstr',9,4)) \
... .show()
+------------+---+----+---+------+
|     fullstr| id|name|age|salary|
+------------+---+----+---+------+
|123asd122000|123| asd| 12|  2000|
|234dfg221000|234| dfg| 22|  1000|
+------------+---+----+---+------+
```

I can also read it from a file. For e.g. I have a file `file.txt` which has a header.

```
% cat file.txt 
fullstr
123asd122000
234dfg221000
322sfg213400
124gse235900
```

Read it using

```
>>> spark.read.option("header","true").csv('file:///Users/bala/Desktop/file.txt').show()
+------------+
|     fullstr|
+------------+
|123asd122000|
|234dfg221000|
|322sfg213400|
|124gse235900|
+------------+
```

Comment: @Soz: Updated with samples on how to read from a file